# Median calculation with condition

Tags: r, numeric, spotfire, calculation, spotfire-analyst

I am calculating median in spotfire using median function with condition if calculated median value is not one of the numbers from which median was calculated then the median should be the next large existing number. For example, if median is 10 but 10 is not one of the numbers and the next number is 12, then median should be 12. How can this be calculated in spotfire or other language such as R?

Answer (score 1):

In R, you could do this:

```
my_median = function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if(na.rm) x = na.omit(x)
  if(length(x) %% 2 == 1) median(x) else median(x[-1])
}
```